# looping Multimap inside Multimap

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, multimap

I have created  Integer and Multimap inside Multimap and I was trying to loop to get the key and value. However for Multimap it returns in array and I couldn't remove the array and get only int.

This is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    Multimap<Integer, Integer> linkedHashMap3 = LinkedListMultimap.create();
    linkedHashMap3.put(1, 2);

    Multimap<Integer, Multimap<Integer, Integer>> linkedHashMap2 = LinkedListMultimap.create();
    linkedHashMap2.put(3, linkedHashMap3);

    for (Entry<Integer, Multimap<Integer, Integer>> st : linkedHashMap2.entries()) {

        System.out.println(st.getValue().keySet());//1
        System.out.println(st.getValue().values());//2
        System.out.println(st.getKey());//2
    }
}
```

the outcome now

```
 [1]
 [2]
   3
```

but I want the outcome to be:

```
 1
 2
 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `flatMap` it:

```
st.values().stream()
    .flatMap(innerMap -> innerMap.values().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: stream() is not available in Multimap

Comment: @Arsenal yeah, it should be on values, my bad